# API Gateway Ocelot does not redirect

Tags: c#, .net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

Making a micro-service architecture with Ocelot I started to build a test service in a separate solution. Everything is working and I can get the mock response to `https://localhost:5101/service/stats/collected`.

Then in another solution I'm making a fresh new webapi project. Then I follow the **getting started** at Ocelot's [official website](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/gettingstarted.html).

Configuring the .json file to use it as a GW I got a 500 from the project if I try to hit `https://localhost:5001/api/stats/collected` and I cannot figure out why ?

Here the main files for the APIGW :

**ocelot.json**

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/service/stats/collected",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5101
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/stats/collected"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
  }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

namespace APIGateway.Base
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(
                    options =>
                {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.pfx", "qwerty123");
                    });
                    options.AddServerHeader = false;
                }
                    )
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config
                        .SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                        .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json")
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureServices(s => {
                    s.AddOcelot();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    //add your logging
                })
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.UseOcelot().Wait();
                })
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace StatsService.Base
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I find out that disabling the SSL on each project by commenting the `options` in the method `UseKestrel` make my GW works.
How can I setup up this to have a secure connexion between my GW and the Service ? Localhost and Prod ?

Comment: You and I are on the same boat. Locally, it does not make sense to use https because the request does not really go outside of the machine, in Prod it is mandatory to have HTTPS. But I want to have the same setup between the development environment and production environment. I could not get this to work. I am starting to think that Ocelot does not support that.

Comment: I think the culprit is this "options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001". Let me know if you were able to figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: Did anyone figured out this yet @secretAgentB

Answer (score 4):

As you are using "localhost" as the hostname, I'd guess that you are using a self signed certificate for localhost. In that case you might have to add

```
"DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator": true
```

to your ReRoutes configuration (see https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html#ssl-errors).

Other options would be:

- using a valid certificate (quite hard to achieve for localhost)
- register the self signed certificate in your user's certificate store as a trustworthy certificate.

Answer (score 2):

I Have to changed ReRoute to Route then my routes redirect correctly.Please Use Route in your ocelot configuration file

Answer (score 0):

You project is enabled for SSL, you have to disabled the SSL and remove the route with HTTPS in the launchSettings.json in all of your WEB API project. It will work successfully.